# Android zxing journeyapps bar code scanner inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, zxing

I'm using the [journeyapps](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded) to have a bar code scan.

My idea is to have an activity that inflates a layout containing an header, and bellow that header, a fragment. Inside that fragment is where I would lunch the bar code scanner so the scanner ideally would scan inside that fragment and the header was always visible.

In my activity I have this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_with_header_and_fragment_placeholder);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Fragment fragment = new Fragment();

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

And in my fragment I have this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dummy_view_with_blank_content, container, false);

    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this).setPrompt("Some prompt").initiateScan();
}
```

The problem is when the bar code scanner is lunched, it takes all the available screen. It is not loaded inside my activity layout `R.layout.activity_with_header_and_fragment_placeholder` so that my header is visible.

Does someone knows how can I solve this?

Comment: It's not possible. It always launches new Activity: [IntentIntegrator.java#L341](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java#L341). You will need to create your own implementation similar to: [CaptureActivity](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/zxing-android-legacy/src/com/google/zxing/client/androidlegacy/CaptureActivity.java)

Answer (score 0):

Reading from the project page, you can provide a [custom layout](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded#custom-layout) to modify the look of the activity/fragment where the app itself is loaded. Try to use that

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that but the problem is that I have a button in my header and cant attach the listener to that button from my activity (the one that lunches the scanner)

Comment: You have access to the source code of the library..just find the class that display the scanner activity/fragment, modify it with your button or menu option and put the listener there, should be enough to achieve your goal